# determining different big O complexity for for loops

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

```
//outer for loop runs at most n times
    for (int w = 1; w < n; w++) {
        // inner for loop at most log(73550/n) times
        for (int y = w; y < 73550; y = y * 2) {
            x = x + w;
        }
        k = k * w;
    }
```

I am really confused on whether the second loop adds to the big O time complexity since it has a set max iteration? would big O be O(n), O(nlog(1/n)) or neither??

```
        int p = 0;
        int q = 0;
        //runs at most 18n^2 times
        while (p < 18 * n * n) {
            if (p % 2 == 0) {
                q++;
            }
            p++;
        }
        //p = 18n^2 q1 = 9n^2
        //runs at most log(9n^2) times
        for (int r = 1; r < q; r = r * 3) {
            q++;
        }
        return p * q;
```

the time complexity of a sequential functions like this is just the larger time complexity right? so it will be O(n^2) ?

```
//runs at most n(4n-1) times
for (int k = 2; k <= 2n(4n-1); k+=2) {
    j++;
}
```

even with the -1 the time complexity will be O(n^2) right?

Comment: Isn't it we consider the worst input data set for defining complexity?

Comment: Do these loops ever terminate?

Comment: yes the value n is just some integer value passed into the function. @MitchelPaulin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First case: `O(n)`, since as you said, there's a constant bound on the number of loop iterations.  It's not typical to have very large constants on loop bounds, so this doesn't tend to be a big deal in most natural algorithms.  If 73550 was actually a non-constant variable, but independent of n, we could give it a name (e.g. m), and say that the complexity is `O(n*log(m))`.

Second case: Yes, `O(n^2)`, for the reason you gave.

Third case: Yes, `O(n^2)`.  First, big-O only provides an upper bound, so the -1 only makes it easier to guarantee the bound.  Second, even if you mean `Ө(n^2)`, it still is, because `n(4n-1) = 4n^2-n`, which is asymptotically larger than `k*n^2` for some constant `k`.  In this case, any `k` less than 4.

Comment: Thank you for your help and clarification. It helps a lot:)